# No resource identifier found for attribute ‘onClick’ in package ‘android’

Tags: android

I am having the following error, when I am trying to run my code.

I googled it out. Many have talked about onclick method notbeing functional for API<=3. I rechecked my API Level.It is 17.

How do I get about running my code.

If need I can post my MainActivity.java code to figure out.

here is the code

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;




import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btn;
private EditText edit;
private Spinner spinner;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    //Log.v("EditText", edit.getText().toString());
                    //Log.v("Spinner", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    String url="http://js-server.xxx.edu:23405/examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample?title="+edit.getText().toString()+"&type="+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Log.v("url",url);
                }
            });



ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =      ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.title_type,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

  //String url="http://js-server.xxx.edu:23405/examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample?title="+edit.getText().toString()+"&type="+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
 // Log.v("url",url);

 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        //Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});


}

private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";
      for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
          InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
  }

  public void readWebpage(View view) {
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://js-server.xxx.edu:23405/examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample?title="+edit.getText().toString()+"&type="+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() });

  }
}
```

All i am trying to do is to fetch the JSON data returned by the server. Then I need to parse the JSON data to form a tabular format. I am not onto this part yet, still stuck on retrieving the JSON data from my server.

My XML file is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="298dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="106dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onclick="readWebpage"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Example Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your code.  Also, it is generally a bad idea to use onClick in the XML.  Register an OnClickListener instead.,

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 : **"...it is generally a bad idea to use onClick in the XML."** - What is your logic behind that statement?

Comment: @Squonk it is less maintainable.  It's similar to using onClick in javascript, it's not explicitly incorrect, it's just not good practice.

Comment: Yes, you need post your code, cause it works. onClick through XML works using Java reflection, there is no difference (very small) so it is good to use it

UPD: agree, it is not safe, easier to break a code because of no strong reference to the method

Comment: DISCLAIMER: The above comment is an **opinion** based on 4 years of Android experience.

Comment: guys..i have posted the code above. also please let me know If i should modify the code to get the JSON data. i think theres no need, still anycase?

Comment: Is your XML attribute `android:onClick="readWebpage"`?

Comment: @Sam yes it is android:onclick="readWebpage"

Comment: @Sam i have posted my code for the XML file also (just now)

Comment: What is your minimum API in your manifest?

Comment: i have these   android:minSdkVersion="8"
                android:targetSdkVersion="16"  in my AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I am with you at that, however the introductory tutorial in Android page does it like that. Of course it is just a tutorial, but they should stress bad practices when they apply them only for demonstration and simplicity. In general, I am unhappy with all the Android resources I have met so far. Seems stackoverflow will be my only decent tutor from now on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android's XML parser is case sensitive. This is incorrect:

```
android:onclick="readWebpage"
```

This is correct:

```
android:onClick="readWebpage"
```